# Should we have a Super User Birthday/Windows 10 Release contest?

Tags: discussion, super-contest

It's crazy to think that on August 18<sup>th</sup> it'll have been [6 years since Super User came to fruition](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/08/super-user-now-public/).  We've also got a new major release for Windows ---- [Windows 10 coming on July 29<sup>th</sup>](http://blogs.windows.com/bloggingwindows/2015/06/01/hello-world-windows-10-available-on-july-29/).

[In times past](https://blog.stackexchange.com/2010/08/super-user-1-year-anniversary-super-contest/), [we've celebrated](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) our birthday [with contests](http://blog.superuser.com/2012/11/14/super-user-contest-winners/) and I was wondering if we'd like to do the same thing this year?  Since the release of Windows 10 is so close, perhaps we could theme the contest to coincide with the release?

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR: Birthday celebration good; Windows 10 "flavoring" bad.

As someone who's never especially enjoyed the close and snuggly relations between Super User and Microsoft - at least among some (vocal) subsets of the community - I'm against "theming" our birthday in the context of the Windows 10 release.

Look, we're not `microsoft.stackexchange.com` or `windows.stackexchange.com`. In practice, we get many questions that are not particular to any OS, and questions about OSes other than Windows, with as much frequency as we get questions about Microsoft products. The topicality rules allow this, so our site casts a pretty wide net. ... Actually, it's not *just* that the topicality rules *allow* questions about non-Windows OSes; it's that the topicality rules don't specifically pick out Microsoft products as being "special" or "extremely on-topic" moreso than any other OS or technology.

In short, if we're not celebrating Fedora releases or Ubuntu releases or Mac OS X releases or VMware Workstation releases or ffmpeg releases, why should we celebrate Windows releases? I think it sends the wrong message to the community and lends an undue amount of support to products of a particular company, and could potentially confuse users into thinking that we **are** `windows.stackexchange.com`, and maybe think twice about asking a good non-Windows question here.

Considering we've never had any contests for any product releases other than Windows, it seems oddly bias to favor a Microsoft OS release as a special event. I was pretty firmly against the thing we did for Windows 8, and I feel the same way about this.

I'm all for getting Windows 10 questions asked and answered here on Super User, but I don't think we need to especially encourage it with any kind of perks or special rewards or contests to make that happen. It'll happen naturally. Our community is large enough and stable enough to be self-sustaining. We have enough askers and answerers to get it done with no marketing or promotion necessary.

Celebrating Super User's 6th anniversary would also be a very nice thing to do. I'm not sure in what *way* we should celebrate, and how that should affect the site (should we have a contest? special features for a limited time? I don't know), but whatever you guys come up with will probably be fine by me. As long as it doesn't have a big Windows logo attached to it.

Comment: `we're not celebrating Fedora releases or Ubuntu releases or Mac OS X` the frequency at which these OS's are released is quite often.  Windows releases (for now) are hit with less frequency.  It's was also just coincidental and I thought it might make a good theme.

Comment: And apparently, it's the last "major" release of Windows. I doubt it, but we'll see

Comment: I invite whomever downvoted to post your own answer with a differing opinion. It's best to let the mods know what you think. "I disagree with this" doesn't really give them a good idea. Do you not want a birthday celebration at all? Do you want Windows 10 themed celebration? Something else entirely? Chime in with your own answer, please.